# Pull and Push Replication from Couchbase local Server to Android Phone

Tags: android, couchdb, replication, couchbase

I am developing and android app which uses couch db.I am new to couch DB.I have set up a couch server locally as given in this manual (http://docs.couchbase.com/couchbase-manual-2.5/cb-install/) and add a document on database using web console ,but I am not able to pull or push the contents from Emulator to couch server.

This is the URL from which I am pulling or pushing locally

```
http://10.0.2.2:5984/_utils/database.html?testDB
```

Can anyone please tell me what is that how I will be able to push a document on a databse created on server.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase and CouchDB are different products. The URL you are referring to in your question is a CouchDB URL. If you want to get to the web ui in Couchbase then you should go to the address below.

`http://10.0.2.2:8091`

Answer (score 0):

On top of that if you are developing a mobile app on Android, you might want to look at the forthcoming Couchbase Lite coupled with the Couchbase Mobile Infrastructure (sync_gateway + Couchbase Server) to try and do a push/pull from device app to back end data store. http://www.couchbase.com/mobile It may streamline what you are doing and provide functionality you do not then have to develop yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old question, but for everyone that should search far an answer I share my experience.

Problem was accessing localhost couch(DB)base instance from emulator or genymotion device. 
This is easily solved in couple of steps (shown in CoucDB but similar is for Couchbase):

1. Go to the your database admin interface through your computer browser `localhost:5984` and click on the **Configuration** menu item:
   [image: Futon menu]
2. In the configuration list find **bind_adress** property located under the `httpd`category. Change the bind adress to `0.0.0.0`
3. Find the internal IP adress of your emulator:
   linux terminal: `ifconfig vboxnet0` or `ifconfig vboxnet1`
   windows has similar `ipconfig` command in the cmd.
4. In your virtual device's browser type in that IP adress with port 5984 (for CouchDB) and you should get sth like this:
   [image: Genymotion browser]

That is all.